# How to use callback result as return of Single.fromCallable?

Tags: rx-java, reactive-programming

Check the code below:

```
Single.fromCallable<User> {
    val accessToken = getCurrentAccessToken()
    if (accessToken == null) {
        throw IllegalStateException("Facebook access token is null")
    } else {
        val request = newMeRequest(accessToken) { user, _ ->
            transform(user)
        }
        prepareRequest(request)
        executeBatchAsync(request)
    }
}
```

The `Callable` prepares a request which will get a `User`. How can I use this user object as the return from the first callable?

Answer (score 0):

Please rephrase your question, it's hard to understand what you want

```
Single.fromCallable<User> {
val accessToken = getCurrentAccessToken()
if (accessToken == null) {
    throw IllegalStateException("Facebook access token is null")
} else {
    val request = newMeRequest(accessToken) { user, _ ->
        transform(user)
    }
    User user = prepareRequest(request)
    executeBatchAsync(request)
    return user;
}
```